# Piping to systemd-cat or logger doesn't work in a cron job

Tags: cron, syslog

I'm running a database backup script via cron, and would like to send the program's output to the system log (so it gets sent to [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/)).

I've been trying to run the following:

```
/opt/orientdb/bin/backup.sh \
  remote:localhost/[database name] \
  root root \
  /db-backup/orientdb-dev/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").zip \
  lvm \
  2>&1 \
| tr '\n' ' ' \
| /usr/bin/systemd-cat -t "orientdb-backup"
```

However, this script outputs to syslog when called directly, but does not include any output when run via cron.

Syslog after running manually (unrelated lines removed):

```
[user]@orientdb-dev:~$ sudo /opt/orientdb/bin/backup.sh remote:localhost/[database name] root root /db-backup/orientdb-dev/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").zip lvm 2>&1 | tr '\n' ' ' | /usr/bin/systemd-cat -t "orientdb-backup"
[user]@orientdb-dev:~$ tail /var/log/syslog
Jan 21 18:16:48 orientdb-dev orientdb-backup[3522]: /opt/orientdb /opt/orientdb/bin/backup.sh: 103: cd: can't cd to /opt/orientdb/databases/[database name]   Volume group "sda1" not found   Cannot process volume group sda1  2018-01-21 18:16:47:716 WARNING No enough physical memory available for DISKCACHE: 581MB (heap=494MB). Set lower Maximum Heap (-Xmx setting on JVM) and restart OrientDB. Now running with DISKCACHE=256MB [orientechnologies] Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot create a connection to remote server address(es): [127.0.0.1:2424]  ERROR # 1 : database freeze failed
```

Cron file:

```
$ cat /etc/cron.d/orientdb-backup 
#Ansible: backup
*/5 * * * * root /opt/orientdb/bin/backup.sh remote:localhost/[database name] root root /db-backup/orientdb-dev/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").zip lvm 2>&1 | tr '\n' ' ' | /usr/bin/systemd-cat -t "orientdb-backup"
```

syslog after cron job runs:

```
Jan 21 18:15:01 orientdb-dev CRON[3438]: (root) CMD (/opt/orientdb/bin/backup.sh remote:localhost/[database name] root root /db-backup/orientdb-dev/$(date +")
Jan 21 18:15:01 orientdb-dev CRON[3437]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

It feels like there's something different between running the command on the shell vs. inside a cron job, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove line breaks?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I figured I'd group the lines together, especially as I might setup automatic alerts based on line contents, so it might be easier to parse the output.  Not committed to removing new lines, I'll decide that later!

In case it helps, I originally left the linebreaks in the output (without piping through `tr`), and messages still didn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: the date format (`$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")`) uses the `%` symbol, which is reserved by cron.

Replacing `%` with `\%` fixed the issue.